# Getting type error while converting object to string using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the following error while trying to convert object to string using Node.js/JavaScript:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at exports.userlogin (/opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/route/route.js:11:19)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/opt/lampp/htdocs/FGDP/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

I am providing my code below:

```
exports.userlogin=function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.user_name;
    var password=req.body.user_pass;
    var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, 'lexelPass');
    var pass=JSON.stringify(ciphertext);
}
```

Here I am getting `ciphertext` variables datatype is object and I need it to convert into string. But here I am getting this type of error.

Comment: Did you console and see the return type of `ciphertext`? 
What type is it ?

Comment: I think `ciphertext` here is either a `word-array` or a `byte-array` and not an object. Do the necessary conversion to object first.

Comment: @ricky : its giving the type `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Object return by `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, 'lexelPass')` statement is of Circular type. Circular type are something like

```js
var obj = {};
obj.obj = obj;
```

So for tackling this thing we can utilize replacer callback function in `JSON.stringify` as a second parameter. By putting logic for discarding the circular object in replacer function.

[check syntax at MDN for replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to convert the `ciphertext` into a string using the `WordArray.toString([encoding])` method.

```
var pass = ciphertext.toString();
```

If you really want to stringify the `WordArray` you can use [`util.inspect(object[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) which automatically replaces circular references with the string `[Circular]` instead of throwing an error, but keep in mind that `util.inspect` is specific to Node.